# Как передать в React id элемента

Tags: javascript, reactjs

пытаюсь разобраться в React js и не могу понять, как мне передавать теперь свойство id элемента, на котором навешена функция.

у меня есть код:

```
class Lable extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <p htmlFor="inp" className="inp">
      <label>
      {InputRequestRoad()}
      <span className="label">1:</span>
      <span className="border"></span>
      </label>
       </p>
    );
  }
}

function InputRequestRoad(prop) {
   function onKeyUp(e) {
     search(e.value);
   }

   return (
     <input type="text" id="road" placeholder="&nbsp;" onKeyUp={onKeyUp({this.id})}/>
   );
  }
ReactDOM.render(
 <Lable />,
document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Как мне id="road" инпута передать в функцию search? так как в функции search начинается разбор инпута и забор его value

```
var field = document.getElementById(name);
console.log(field.value)
```

или вообще как сразу его vakue передавать после каждого нажатия клавиши? 
По доке и примерам пока не могу понять этого.

Comment: вроде получилось вот таким путем <input type="text" id="road" placeholder="&nbsp;" onKeyUp={() => onKeyUp("road")}/>. Но если кто подскажет правильность расстановки компонентов или укажет на ошибки, с радостью выслушаю

Comment: правда в это случае придется дублировать код, чтобы передавать разные id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Lable extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
<p htmlFor="inp" className="inp">
      <label>
       <input type="text" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/>
      <span className="label">1:</span>
      <span className="border"></span>
      </label>
       </p>
    );
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.props.onSearch(e.target.value);
  }
}

function search(text) {
  console.log(text);
}
 

React.render(
    <Lable onSearch={search}/>,
    document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Функцию search можно передать как параметр внутрь компоненты: <Lable onSearch={search}/>

Comment: спасибо большое, дошел до такого решения .....id={this.props.id} onKeyUp={() => search(this.props.id)} и при объявление компонента передаю свойство id с нужным именем

Comment: Тут можно посмотреть: https://codepen.io/gutulvadim/pen/VgwzKZ

Comment: спасибо, класс, для пробования вариантов самое оно.